# Comments: update gives 403 forbidden insufficient permissions

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, google-apis-explorer

I tried this API [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/comments/update) and in my code and got this error everywhere. However, other methods, such as commentThreads.insert() or comments.delete(), work fine, so I don't think this issue is scopes or OAuth 2.0 authorization related.

Here is the response I get:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "The comment could not be updated due to insufficient permissions. The request might not be properly authorized.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "The comment could not be updated due to insufficient permissions. The request might not be properly authorized.",
        "domain": "youtube.comment",
        "reason": "forbidden",
        "location": "body",
        "locationType": "other"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

UPD:
Apparently, you can only update the comment under your own video. But you can delete your comment from any video. I don’t know why they did it that way and didn't even write about it in the docs. I also wrote to them on https://issuetracker.google.com/

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please take the time to absorb [SO's recommendations](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) addressed to new users. You may take the [tour]; then do read [what's on-topic here](/help/on-topic) and provide a [mre].